# If statement is giving too many arguments error

Tags: excel, if-statement, error-handling, excel-formula, multiple-columns

I have an excel formula where I have to get the difference of the days between two columns which have day/month/year date. The formula works fine as long as the difference-column does not encounter a blank date in one of them two; basically if one of the two dates column is blank the formula displays weird numbers like 344440.

I wanted to solve my problem with an if statement which works fine for one column (column S, one of the column with dates which could be blank), but gives me all sorts of errors when I try to input that column Q could also have a blank cell (other date column).

Thank you guys.

So far I have tried:

```
=IF(S14= "","",IF(Q14 = "","",NETWORKDAYS(Q14,S14)),NETWORKDAYS(Q14,S14))
```

or

```
=IF(S14="","",NETWORKDAYS(Q14,S14), AND(Q14="","",NETWORKDAYS(Q14,S14)))
```

Also tried iferror/ifna, no luck so far.

Comment: Your first one just needed the second NETWORKDAYS removed: `=IF(S14= "","",IF(Q14 = "","",NETWORKDAYS(Q14,S14)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IF` statement follows this generic pattern:

```
=IF(CONDITION, VALUE TO OUTPUT IF CONDITION IS TRUE, VALUE TO OUTPUT IF CONDITION IS FALSE)
```

I'd recommend using an `OR` statement to simplify the formula like this:

```
=IF(OR(S14="",Q14=""),"",NETWORKDAYS(Q14,S14))
```

Basically, the `OR` first checks if one or both of the relevant cells are blank and outputs an empty string if that is the case. If both cells have values it will calculate the `NETWORKDAYS`.

Your first formula would also work, you just have to remove the last argument:

```
=IF(S14="","",IF(Q14="","",NETWORKDAYS(Q14,S14)))
```

Comment: The formula you corrected works like a charm! Thanks a lot. Before I close this question, can I know why did I have to remove the last argument? Thanks again!!

Comment: The `IF` formula only takes three arguments (see the second line of my answer), passing a fourth argument will produce the error you encountered. The first argument is the condition that decides which value is given as the output. The second argument is the output value you want if the condition is true. The third argument is the output value you want if the condition is false. There is simply no need for a fourth argument, since you can cover all cases with this simple structure.